# Unexpected behaviour of function used in conjunction with lapply/sapply?

Tags: r

This

```
mult_six <- function(x) {
  y <- x * 6
}

mult_six(7)
```

returns nothing (as expected), and `y` is not globally assigned (also as exptected, since assignment takes place in the scope of the function, not in the parent environment - so `y` returns `Error: object 'y' not found` - completely normal)

But

```
sapply(c(1,2,3), mult_six)
```

returns

```
[1]  6 12 18
```

(and `lapply()` returns the list equivalent).

I do not understand why `lapply`/`sapply` would behave any differently to calling the function on each element separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know functions by default return the last line in the function, however, since a value is assigned in this function it doesn't explicitly display the result but if you use `print` you can see it.

```
print(mult_six(7))
#[1] 42
```

Comment: I see. So `mult_six(7)` *is* returning a result, even though it's not printed to the console? I had assumed it *wasn't* going to return a result, but also that it would print to the console if it did return a result. Do you know where I can read more about this?

Comment: I am trying to find a good resource as well where functions are explained in detail.

Answer (score 0):

We can just wrap with `()`

```
(mult_six(7))
#[1] 42
```

The assignment to `y<-` is not needed.  It would be

```
mult_six <- function(x) {
     x * 6
  }
```